# C# Append Timestamp to Filepath

Tags: c#, file-io, timestamp

I have the following problem or question,
I have this function

```
private void SavePic(Canvas canvas, string filename)
    {
        RenderTargetBitmap renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap(
         (int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height,
         96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        // needed otherwise the image output is black
        canvas.Measure(new Size((int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height));
        canvas.Arrange(new Rect(new Size((int)canvas.Width, (int)canvas.Height)));

        renderBitmap.Render(canvas);

        //JpegBitmapEncoder encoder = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
        PngBitmapEncoder encoder = new PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(BitmapFrame.Create(renderBitmap));

        using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
        {

            encoder.Save(file);
        }
    }
```

and the corresponding call
`SavePic(mySuperDefaultPainting, @"C:\KinDraw\out.png");`

Now I wanted to attach the file name the date + time?
You can grab this DateTime function in the function call?

maybe I can someone help here?

Comment: These will help: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/system.datetime.now.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Answer (score 3):

try **(Updated for File Path)**:

```
string fileName=string.Format("{0}-{1:ddMMMyyyy-HHmm}.png", @"C:\KinDraw\out", 
                                                    DateTime.Now);
if(!Directory.Exists(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName)))
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.GetDirectoryName(fileName));
}

SavePic(mySuperDefaultPainting, fileName);
```

Say the time is **29-JAN-2013 07:30 PM** it will give you: `C:\KinDraw\out-29JAN2013-1930.png`.

But please check details about `CreateDirectory` on [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/54a0at6s.aspx). Also look for `Exceptions` and wrap in `try-catch` blocks.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips and advice, but he always complains and crashes if the directory for the output not exisitert?
Gibts there a way to create the directory if it does not exist?

Answer (score 2):

```
string timestamp =DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy.HHmmss");
SavePic(mySuperDefaultPainting, @"C:\KinDraw\out"+timestamp+".png");
```

**Update: (to create the directory if it does not exist)**

```
if (!Directory.Exists(filepath))
    Directory.CreateDirectory(filepath);
```

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks for all the tips and advice, but he always complains and crashes if the directory for the output not exisitert?
Gibts there a way to create the directory if it does not exist?

Comment: @Avishek your updated statement will always return false when checking for directory and giving path that ends with file.

Comment: @viv1d : No, you have to assign only directory name(without file-name) to `filepath`

Answer (score 1):

Try to add this at the beginning of your code:

```
var extension = Path.GetExtension(filename);
var newName = filename.Replace(filename, extension) + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:dd") + extension;
```

Comment: string.Format() is your friend.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips and advice, but he always complains and crashes if the directory for the output not exisitert?
Gibts there a way to create the directory if it does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

Just put this line in there:

```
string stampedFileName = filename.Replace(".",
    string.Format("{0:YYYY-mm-dd hhmmss}", DateTime.UtcNow) + ".");
```

and then change

```
using (FileStream file = File.Create(filename))
```

to

```
using (FileStream file = File.Create(stampedFilename))
```

It is important to use `DateTime.UtcNow` rather than `DateTime.Now` because the former is not influenced by daylight saving time.

**EDIT:** The format I propose above has the advantage that sorting your filenames alphabetically then automatically also sorts them chronologically.

Comment: Thanks for all the tips and advice, but he always complains and crashes if the directory for the output not exisitert?
Gibts there a way to create the directory if it does not exist?

Comment: if (!Directory.Exist(path))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

Answer (score -1):

This is how I did it and it works. Tweaked @Avishek code a bit to make it work for mine. No need to delete file or lose what's in it.

Call "Rename()" method after you output the file..

```
public static void Rename()
        {
            string timestamp = DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyyy.HHmmss"); 
            string originalFile = @"C:\Users\Data_Output\" + fileName + ".csv"; 
            string newFile = @"C:\Users\Data_Output\" + fileName + "_" + timestamp + ".csv";

            File.Move(originalFile, newFile);

        }
```

Comment: This is a backwards solution. There's no need to first save the file with the wrong name and then rename it to the right name. Just save it with the right name the first time.