# Windows Phone 8.1 - Saved bitmap shows up in the Photos app under "older photos"

Tags: date, windows-phone-8.1, jpeg, photo

I am making a Windows Phone 8.1 runtime XAML app. In the app I'm saving a RenderTargetBitmap as a jpg file to a new folder in the Pictures Library. I am able to save the jpg using BitmapEncoder but when I open the Photos app the saved jpg does not have a date and is grouped under "older photos". I tried setting the dateTaken but that made no difference. I am testing this on the emulator.

Any ideas why it this occurring and what I need to do for the saved jpg to show up with the date under the correct month group?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case anyone else is having the same issue, I wanted to post an update. Once I was able to test my app on a phone, and not on the emulator, the issue went away after about a day.

My app is saving the jpg files into a dedicated album (folder) and I guess it takes some time for the phone to recognize the new folder as a source of pictures that needs to be processed. After about a day of having the pictures show up under "older photos" in the default Photos app, any new jpg in my album was dated correctly and showed up in the correct place.

Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

try using a variable with a date/time function in it(using windows library) and ship it with the picture u saved and use that variable to place that image.

Alternatively:
[C# Append Timestamp to Filepath](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14578592/c-sharp-append-timestamp-to-filepath)

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/215036/how-to-apply-time-stamp-to-image-in-csharp

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you please give more details? I am not really sure what you mean. I looked at the links you sent but that doesn't help.

Comment: See as far the links are concerned, they are a simple way to do what you are trying to achieve, if you name them according to timestamps eg-20150607.jpg so that would automatically do the process. Secondly for the main album, you can save the current time like:
 
public static String GetTimestamp(this DateTime value)
{
    return value.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff");
}
the above function would get you a time stamp and you can ship this with the image also u can set the time stamp value of the image as this variable.

Comment: Thanks again, but I already have a timestamp in the filename. The issue is in the default Photos app on the phone. The saved jpg there is grouped under the "older photos" group and the jpg has no date displayed there. I need to know which file/image property is the Photos app using for the photo date it displays and groups by.

Comment: I am not able to understand what is it that's the issue to be fixed, if the images are going behind under older pictures, a simple way is, In windows phone phone the images are saved as WP_20150605_003.jpg which means "WindowsPhone_2015/06/05(YYYY/MM/DD)_serial of the image(001,002,003,...) do note that serial of the image must be of the order 001 not 1 else it doesn't work  so while naming your image you can follow the same format. if this doesn't solve your issue, please illustrate what exactly is the issue.

Comment: Aditya, I am already saving the jpg with that filename format. The issue is that the default Photos app is not using the filename to display the date and group the images. If you save an image from the web it will be displayed with a date, no matter the filename. There is some file property that is used for the dates in the Photos app, and I need to know what that property is, and how to set it.

Comment: I recently seeing your issue created an application carrying out the process as yours, I used the following link code, it worked for me, please do have a look:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150592.aspx

do let me know did it work or not!

Comment: Thank you so much Aditya for all your effort. I cannot use FileSavePicker. I need to save the jpg programmatically, without the users involvement. I am currently saving the jpg using BitmapEncoder.

Comment: No problem, If you find an answer do post here for future references many Thanks